# TCP Socket Read Variable Length Data w/o Framing or Size Indicators

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am currently writing code to transfer data to a remote vendor. The transfer will take place over a TCP socket. The problem I have is the data is variable length and there are no framing or size markers. Sending the data is no problem, but I am unsure of the best way to handle the returned data.

The data is comprised of distinct "messages" but they do not have a fixed size. Each message has an 8 or 16 byte bitmap that indicates what components are included in this message. Some components are fixed length and some are variable. Each variable length component has a size prefix for that portion of the overall message.

When I first open the socket I will send over messages and each one should receive a response. When I begin reading data I should be at the start of a message. I will need to interpret the bitmap to know what message fields are included. As the data arrives I will have to validate that each field indicated by the bitmap is present and of the correct size.

Once I have read all of the first message, the next one starts. My concern is if the transmission gets cut partway through a message, how can I recover and correctly find the next message start?

I will have to simulate a connection failure and my code needs to automatically retry a set number of times before canceling that message.

I have no control over the code on the remote end and cannot get framing bytes or size prefixes added to the messages.

Best practices, design patterns, or ideas on the best way to handle this are all welcomed.

Comment: How do you know if the bitmap is 8 vs 16 bytes from message to message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a user's point of view, TCP is a *stream* of data, just like you might receive over a serial port.  There are no packets and no markers.

A non-blocking read/recv call will return you what has currently arrived at which point you can parse that.  If, while parsing, you run out of data before reaching the end of the message, read/recv more data and continue parsing.  Rinse.  Repeat.  Note that you could get *more* bytes than needed for a specific message if another has followed on its heels.

A TCP stream will not lose or re-order bytes.  A message will not get truncated unless the connection gets broken or the sender has a bug (e.g. was only able to write/send part and then never tried to write/send the rest).  You cannot continue a TCP stream that is broken.  You can only open a new one and start fresh.

Comment: I think the missing piece of information from the vendor, is what exactly happens when the TCP socket disconnects and then my code reconnects. When I reconnect will the first data be the continuation of any message that was partially sent or will it retry the entire message.

Comment: @JamesCrow, you are correct.  TCP is easy to predict.  Vendors less so.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A TCP stream cannot be "cut" mid-message and then resumed.

If there is a short enough break in transmission then the O/S at each end will cope, and packets retransmitted as necessary, but that is invisible to the end user application - as far as it's concerned the stream is contiguous.

If the TCP connection does drop completely, both ends will have to re-open the connection.  At that point, the transmitting system ought to start over at a new message boundary.

Comment: message != TCP packet.  Design specifications from the vendor stated that a message could be transmitted by more than one TCP packet. If I receive a partial message, then the TCP connection drops, the next data I receive could be a continuation of the previous message or the start of a new message.

Comment: @JamesCrow: If the connection drops, they are not going to keep sending packets/message from the server, as their side will drop as well. The client will have to open a new connection. At which point, depending on the protocol, you can negotiate to start where you left off, or start fresh. Most protocols choose to start fresh.

Comment: @JamesCrow I never mentioned packets, I said "stream".  My whole point was that TCP streams don't "drop then resume", at least not as far as the user space socket code is concerned - the kernel hides that.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you would probably have a lot easier of a time using a networking framework (like netty), or a different IO mechansim entirely, like Iteratee IO with Play 2.0.